# How to connect java program with oracle 11g

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g

I have this code by JAVA

```
public class Mian {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

         try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.Driver.OracleDriver");
            Connection conn =  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:aaa","aaa","aaa");
            Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("error : " + e);
        }  
    }
}
```

I can not connect with my Database , created by oracle 11g

```
Database name = aaa ,,, user name = aaa ,,, password = aaa
```

and I import the Driver in my project ojdbc6.jar

Why I show This ERROR with i run the program ?

> error : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.Driver.OracleDriver

Comment: Try with `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` (lowercase d). And, if I remember correctly, the driver was moved to `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver` (and the first one is deprecated).

Comment: Have you tried searching what `ClassNotFoundException` means?

Comment: after my Edit , it's show new ERROR "java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor" , what does this code mean  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anytime you see ClassNotFoundException, you have one of two problems:

1. You are using the wrong name for a class
2. Something missing from your classpath.

In this case, you need to use "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver", as suggested earlier.

You also need a jar file from Oracle named "ojdbc#number#.jar", where #number# is the minimum version of Java you want your code to execute on. EG, "ojdbc6.jar" is only for Java 6 or newer.

If your code actually compiles, then you have this jar in your compile classpath. You will also need it in your runtime classpath when you execute your code.

Are you really sure, you have a copy of Oracle running on localhost with a SID or service name of "aaa"? That seems extremely unlikely. If you're using Oracle Exppress, then it is "XE". That means your URL would be:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","aaa","aaa"
```